# How to convert date (without knowing the kind) to string

Tags: ios, string, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have an `array` of `NSDate` objects that I'm trying to convert to a `string`. My way of converting them is with `NSDateFormat`, but, if there's another better way, I'd be happy to hear.

The most things a `date` would have is:

```
Days-Hours-Minutes-Seconds-Milliseconds
```

But some will have less, like:

```
Minutes-Seconds-Milliseconds
```

Or even less. Now I will have to convert them to a `string`. Would I have to create `if statements` to determine if it has days, hours, and so on, or is there an easier way of doing this?

Comment: Do you at least have a list of all the possibilities? If so, you can just try them one after another.

Comment: Or perhaps you can distinguish the possibilities just by counting hyphens? That's an easy one.

Comment: Try using // Using `NSDataDetector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example using `NSDataDetector` (Swift 2.0):

```
let textDate = "dan's march 31, 1975 12:34 pm";

do {
    let dd = try NSDataDetector(types: NSTextCheckingType.Date.rawValue)
    if let tcr :NSTextCheckingResult = dd.firstMatchInString(textDate, options:[], range:NSMakeRange(0, textDate.utf16.count)),
       let date = tcr.date {
            print("date: \(date)")
        }
}
catch {
    print("Data Detector error!")
}
```

Output:

> date: 1975-03-31 16:34:00 +0000

Comment: I'm using an earlier version of swift

Comment: Also, If I'm not wrong, I thing you can use just textDate.count in swift 2.0

Comment: @Jessica A Swift 1.x answer will be outdated in a week so it really does not make sense at this point. The `utf16` is needed, this is an Objective method and expects a count of utf16 code units. 2.0 has utf8, utf16 and utf32 count properties. The error message is: 'count' is unavailable: there is no universally good answer, see the documentation comment for discussion. Swift.String:40:7: note: 'count' has been explicitly marked unavailable here.