# How would I convert "6 September, 2015" to NSDate() in Swift?

Tags: swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

How would I convert "6 September, 2015" to NSDate() in Swift?

Comment: ["Date Formatters"](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DataFormatting/Articles/dfDateFormatting10_4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002369-SW1) in Apple's "Data Formatting Guide" might be good place to start ...

Comment: If you don't know the format : [NSDataDetector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32383265/convert-date-without-knowing-the-kind-to-string)

Answer (score 3):

So I'm gonna assume you've got a `String`, and you wanna convert it into a `NSDate`.

The easiest way to do this is through the NSDateFormatter.

Check [this](http://userguide.icu-project.org/formatparse/datetime) website to see how to use the syntax for date input, and the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/index.html).

```
let dateToConvert = "6 September, 2015"

let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM, yyyy"
let date = dateFormatter.dateFromString(dateToConvert)   //"Sep 6, 2015, 12:00 AM"
```

Best of luck!

Comment: The most important part is missing. `dateFormatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")`. Otherwise that will fail for all user who don't use an english locale.

Answer (score 1):

As commented, I would encourage you to review the docs as these are the same steps as Objective-C.

You can use [`dateFromString`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDateFormatter/dateFromString:):

```
var dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "d MMMM, yyyy"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("6 September, 2015")
```

Once you have an `NSDate`, you can use another date formatter for the `mm-dd-yyyy` output.

Comment: Ahha posted at the same time! Look out though, EEEE refers to the day of the week.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this.

```
let dateString = "6 September, 2015"
let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"

let dateFormat: NSDate? = formatter.dateFromString(dateString)

if let date = dateFormat {
    // Do something with it.
}
```